# Open Graph user-generated-photos action approval process

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, photos

To submit an action that uses user-generated photos, I have to give step-by-step instructions on how to trigger that action using a test user account.

However, since user generated photos are a special property, they don't work for test users until the action is approved.

So, the given instructions I give in the approval process won't work until the action is approved. It appears I'm in a catch-22 situation.

Is there a way to get around this?

**Update:** We solved the problem by just giving them access to one of our admin accounts (and changing the password afterwards). A bit sketchy, but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Giving admin right seems to work also, but probably easier way is:

1. Just take step by step screenshots how your posting flow goes on your app/website. Then just take another screenshot about how the shared photo/post looks on your FB timeline (since you have admin right to your on FB app).
2. Put these as step by step "guide/explanation" html and add link to your action submission.
3. Wait for approval ;)